# Make a trade contract between two tokens like (EOS) & (SYS)

Tags: smart-contract, eosio.token

hello everyone i made a small contract that trade between two tokens using eosio.token but if i wasn't work on local test how  can i have access to EOS tokens  or SYS in the main net and how can i do that ?

Comment: Your question is very vague. Are you asking how you could set up an Escrow contract on mainnet?

Comment: i mean can i access to contract token of eos or other token and got a notify after exchange ?